# Is there a way to configure which files are non-binary (textual) in Intellij Idea so they would be included in a patch?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, patch

I've got some custom filename extensions in project (like '.default' or even no-extension files). Yet these files are textual. Can I configure Intellij so files with certain extensions would be included in svn patch? I tried to find such an option but I failed.

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2013? Please, upvote it then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say about IntelliJ IDEA, but if your working copy includes

```
abc.default
abc1.default
text.txt
image.bmp
```

and you want to generate patch for .default ones, you can run the following command:

**[`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html)**`*.default > mydefaults.patch`

See also [SVNBook | Examine the details of your local modifications](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.diff).